# A clickable grid of JLabel boxes

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I am new to Java GUI and I am trying to place a grid of 7 x 12 Jlabels/Boxes. I need to then be able to get the X and Y co-ordinates of each box.
When I run the below code it shows every box as 0,0... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;


public class GridPanel extends JPanel{

private final int HEIGHT = 7;
private final int WIDTH = 12;
private final int TOTAL_BOXES = HEIGHT * WIDTH;
JLabel box[];

public GridPanel()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout(7,12));


     box = new JLabel[TOTAL_BOXES];

        for (int x = 0;x<box.length;x++){

            box[x]=new JLabel("");
            box[x].setOpaque(true);
            box[x].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
            box[x].setBackground(Color.white);
            box[x].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            int a = box[x].getX();
            int b = box[x].getY();
            String test = b + "," + a;
            box[x].setText(test);


        }

        System.out.println(box[45].getX());

        for (int x = 0;x<box.length;x++)
            add(box[x]);

}
```

}

Comment: First question, why do you need to know the x/y coordinates of the labels?

Comment: They will become variables which will then relate to objects in the back end of the program...

Comment: Why haven't you used the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` variables, while creating your `JLabel`s?!

Comment: Oh yeah HEIGHT and WIDTH were just some leftovers I haven't taken out yet...

Comment: @Daviepark and what exactly are you planning to do by making them variables ? :) Maybe we can suggest an alternative.